# grails and double values saving

Tags: grails, double, gsp

In my Grails project I have a Domain Class with a double field as follows:

```
double totalAmount;
```

the value of this field are calculated by a sum done after selecting values in a multiple select. the function for sum values is in the controller, as follows:

```
def sumReceiptItems(){



    params.list("receiptItemsSelected").each {i-> println("element "+i)}
    def appList =  params.list("receiptItemsSelected")

    List<ReceiptItem> allSelectedIds = ReceiptItem.findAllByIdInList(params.receiptItemsSelected.split(',')*.toLong())

    def totalAmount = allSelectedIds.amount.sum()

    println("totalAmount is = "+totalAmount)
    render totalAmount as Double        

}
```

the function works well. After function calling, to update the field in GSP page, I use a javascript method as follows:

```
function updateTotalAmount(name, data, presentNullAsThis){
  if(data !=null)
     document.getElementById(name).value= data;
  else 
     document.getElementById(name).value=presentNullAsThis;
}
```

The javascript works and I see the updating of the field at runtime, but the double value is shown with a dot, and not with comma to separate decimal values. Infact, after clicking by save button to save the instance of the domain class, the value is saved without separating decimals, for example:

if the value into the fiels is 10.50 it is stored as 1050

In this discussion [how can save a double type correctly in grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492044/how-can-save-a-double-type-correctly-in-grails) I've read a similar problem, but solution is not good for my issue.

Anybody can help me?

Comment: "*but the double value is shown with a dot, and not with comma to separate decimal values*" - were you expecting it to be shown separated by comma like `10,50` for `10.50`?

Comment: @dmahapatro for me comma or dot is the same, the problem is that if I edit manually the field described in the post and use a comma to separate decimals, value is correctly stored. If I use a dot, it is not stored correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem in this way:

1. I've updated my Javascript as follows:

   ```
   function updateTotalAmount(name, data, presentNullAsThis)
   {
       var data2 = data.toString().replace(/\./g, ',');
       if(data2 != null) document.getElementById(name).value= data2;
       else document.getElementById(name).value= presentNullAsThis;
   }
   ```
2. I've removed "type="number"" in the gsp related field

Answer (score 1):

Values with decimal separator depends on the current `Locale` of the user. Normally you use `g.formatNumber` in the view to display correctly the value.

You can check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713166/decimal-separator-in-numberformat) on how to discover the decimal separator for a Locale.

To get the user's Locale use:

```
Locale locale = RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how this can help me in my issue. Can you explain it to me in a clear way?

Comment: You need to know the Locale and get the correct decimal separator to use in your JavaScript, otherwise your value will be stored incorrectly.

Comment: sorry but, as you can see in my Javascript code, I don't give any indication about the decimal separator. So, in controller I've printed the value after the sum() and it has a point separator, not a comma...I need to know how I can resolve this issue. Can you please edit your answer to give a complete sample, based on my code?